# JQuery Ajax Upload of files

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, form-data

I know this is a bit of a talking point with Ajax Files uploads (images). But i have to implement an Ajax file up-loader however my main concern is browser compatibility, my code would need to work across I.E 7 + Firefox + Chrome + Safari + mobile browsers. I know mainly the issue will be with I.E 7 but my other concern now is with mobile browsers.

Due to incompatibility i want to stay away from html5 as i beleive this only works with Firefox, Chrome and Safari

The following html code will be the input:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload"  action="upload.php">  
<input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple />  
<button type="submit" id="btn">Upload Files!</button>  
</form>
```

As you can see this will be also using form-data. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction for form uploading (without i-frames) or let me know if this is possible cross platform including I.E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is this jQuery plugin :

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

As far as they stated they support IE 6+ , here :

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support

On a personal note , i have used this plugin and its pretty nice and simple.

Comment: only answer but i ended up checking if window.FormData === undefined and then if so upload to iframe else use FormData